# Why aromatic compounds have pi-electrons clouds above and below the plane

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I was reading a text and it asked "aromatic compounds have pi-electron clouds above and below the plane due to?". Someone, please help.

Comment: Hmm, do you know what *aromatic compounds* are in the first place? If not, check the wikipedia article for [Aromaticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromaticity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just how [Aromaticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromaticity) is defined. Simply put, it means you have delocalized $\pi$ electrons in some circular structure. Being above and below the molecular plane is simply a property of $\pi$ orbitals/electrons.

Answer (score 1):

The orbitals are akin to normal modes of vibration. Sigma bonds have no nodes, like the fundamental vibration of a guitar string. Pi bonds have one node (in the same plane as the atomic nuclei), and that is like the first harmonic of a guitar string (pluck it while holding your finger gently against the midpoint of the string). The note is one octave higher than the fundamental--higher frequency means higher energy.